# Best way to monitor file transfer (Java and C)

Tags: java, c

I want to monitor file transfer in a web application. This web application can show the transfer progress using progress bar and also to manually resume failed transfer etc.

FYI, I wrote my own file transfer protocol in C language then I use Java to call that protocol.

For now, I write all my transferred data in database (the C code does this) and use it for monitoring in web application. Is this the best way to monitor my file transfer or is there any other way that I can use to monitor the file transfer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right while you are transferring file you are putting the data into the database so web application could take it and show for progress?
If yes, then it probably would not be a good way. Database is more to make reports for all files that you ever have sent and such things.

To show status for the current file you just need to implement function in the code that implements your protocol that will return current status. And then using ajax you may call this function each 1 second or smth like that to update the progress bar in runtime.

Comment: yes you are right, for now I stored my transfer data in database, and use it for progress bar and table in web application. So this is a bad idea I think? I'll try your suggestion, thanks for your help..

Comment: The data base is too expansive to track the progress and it will add a lot of overhead. Protocol world is more realtime, so you may need just direct functions calls, as I said. And what I want to add is that database concept is more for storing and aggregating data for persistency. Hope it helps)